# cannot build gcc cross compiler for os dev x86 "make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2"

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, osdev

I just got my new intel mac, and it seems that I cant compile the gcc compiler for cross compiling for my x86 32 bit os.

I also tried to get help on this gh page:
https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/tree/master/11-kernel-crosbuild/gencondmd.o%20../build-x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0/libiberty/libiberty.a%20Undefined%20symbols%20for%20architecture%20x86_64:%20%22_target_flags%22,%20referenced%20from:%20___cxx_global_var_init%20in%20gencondmd.o%20ld:%20symbol(s)%20not%20found%20for%20architecture%20x86_64%20clang:%20error:%20linker%20command%20failed%20with%20exit%20code%201%20(use%20-v%20to%20see%20invocation)compiler

LOGS:

```
MY_NAME's macbookpro:gcc-build chengsihan$ make all-gcc
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
true "AR_FLAGS=rc" "CC_FOR_BUILD=gcc" "CFLAGS=-g -O2" "CXXFLAGS=-g -O2" "CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=-g -O2" "CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-g -O2" "INSTALL=/usr/bin/install -c" "INSTALL_DATA=/usr/bin/install -c -m 644" "INSTALL_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/install -c" "INSTALL_SCRIPT=/usr/bin/install -c" "LDFLAGS=" "LIBCFLAGS=-g -O2" "LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-g -O2" "MAKE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make" "MAKEINFO=makeinfo --split-size=5000000 " "PICFLAG=" "PICFLAG_FOR_TARGET=" "SHELL=/bin/sh" "EXPECT=expect" "RUNTEST=runtest" "RUNTESTFLAGS=" "exec_prefix=/usr/local/i386elfgcc" "infodir=/usr/local/i386elfgcc/share/info" "libdir=/usr/local/i386elfgcc/lib" "prefix=/usr/local/i386elfgcc" "tooldir=/usr/local/i386elfgcc/i386-elf" "AR=ar" "AS=as" "CC=gcc" "CXX=g++" "LD=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" "LIBCFLAGS=-g -O2" "NM=nm" "PICFLAG=" "RANLIB=ranlib" "DESTDIR=" DO=all multi-do # /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
true  DO=all multi-do # /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make
test -f config.h || (rm -f stamp-h1 && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make stamp-h1)
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
g++   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE  -o build/gencondmd \
            build/gencondmd.o ../build-x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0/libiberty/libiberty.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_target_flags", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in gencondmd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [build/gencondmd] Error 1
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm very new to macOS I'm very use to windows and linux.

Comment: Are you building gcc and binutils with the same target?